# Michael Spivak's Calculus - Chapter 1 Problem 6

Tags: real-analysis

I am brushing up my calculus concepts using Michael Spivak's book. There's a problem in the first chapter - Basic Properties of numbers,

> Prove that if $x<y$ and $n$ is odd, then $x^{n}<y^{n}$.

I am aware that $x^n -y^n=(x-y)(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}y+\dotsb+xy^{n-2}+y^{n-1})$. As the first term $x-y<0$, my approach is to prove that for all $n=2k+1$, where k is a non-negative integer, the second term in the factorization is positive.

I was able to divide it into three sub-cases: (i) $x<0,\:y<0$ (ii) $x>0,\:y>0$ and (iii) $x<0,\:y>0$. However, I cannot conclude that the second factor would be positive in case (iii).

Is there a better approach to this? Should I use mathematical induction? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In case (iii), an odd exponent will preserve the signs of $x$ and $y$, so $y^n$ must remain greater than $x^n$.

Comment: Isn't (iii) obvious? $x^n< 0, y^n> 0.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 1: $x < 0 < y \Rightarrow x^n < 0 < y^n \Rightarrow x^n < y^n$

Case 2: $x < y < 0$, let $x =-x', y = -y' \Rightarrow x' > y' > 0 \Rightarrow x^n = (-x')^n = -(x')^n<-(y')^n=(-y')^n = y^n$

Case 3: $x = 0, 0 < y \Rightarrow x^n = 0 < y^n \Rightarrow x^n < y^n$

Case 4: $x < 0, y = 0 \Rightarrow x^n < 0 = y^n \Rightarrow x^n < y^n$

Case 5: $0 < x < y \Rightarrow 1<\dfrac{y}{x}\Rightarrow 1 < \left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^n=\dfrac{y^n}{x^n}\Rightarrow x^n < y^n$